# Drag drop views in constraintlayout move views to top left corner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am new to constrain layout and after reading documentations i know that view must have 1 horizontal and 1 vertical coordinates but whenever i drag a new view into design it move to 0,0 coordinates

[image: View At top left]

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="181dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_friend" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I already set views vertical and horizontal constrain but it still hangs at the top left also tried with vertical and horizontal bias but views sticks to top left.Please help

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422887/all-items-merges-to-top-left-in-constraint-layout-android-studio) but not working for me.

Comment: Its a android studio layout editor specific bug. Have you tried running the app and see ? Also try selecting **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil are you sure it's a bug not an issue on my side?

Comment: yes happens sometimes. Layout editor tries to show the output the you will see once you run the app but it is not 100% accurate all the time. Have you tried running the app and see where you view actually lies when app is running ?

Comment: I know it would show at right place on app but that's what constrainlayout meant for to simplify process of designing

Comment: that's why I said it is a bug. Either try going to **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart** or  update your android studio. What version are you using ?

Comment: Android Studio 3.5.2

Comment: have you tried invalidating cache and restart as well ?  Does your problem still persists ?

Comment: Yes the problem still there in my android studio not getting it work at all

Comment: Meanwhile try completely resetting android studio by closing android studio then deleting the `.AndroidStudio3.5` folder from your USERS\\[PC NAME] and re launching it again. Hope it helps

Comment: Also can you can share your app `build.gradle` file I want to see which version of `ConstraintLayout` and `appcompat` you are using

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil i am using  `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2" ` and
 i will try with deleting android studio files

Comment: Sure and also try to use `'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'` instead. It is the latest stable version.

Comment: `1.1.3` doesn't support motion layout which is our need

Comment: then try an older or newer version of `2.0` from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support.constraint/constraint-layout?repo=google

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes if we move around commits. For me it's mostly build related issue. Building the project or make project would fix this issue.